# Vue3 how to implement dynamic components with Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to use dynamic component functionality with Composition API in Vue3. I have no problem with Options API. I followed this instruction: [link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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)

There is my code:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import General from "../components/ContractGeneral.vue";
import Networks from "../components/ContractDetails.vue";
const tabs = {
  General,
  Networks,
};
let currentTab = ref("Networks");
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab" @click="currentTab = tab">
          <div>
            <p>{{ tab }}</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div></div>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <keep-alive>
        <component :is="tabs[currentTab]"></component>
      </keep-alive>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>
```

and the problem is, that {{tab}} in my case shows a full component object, not just a name like 'General'. It shows something like this:  "src/components/ContractGeneral.vue", "__hmrId": "f8a99314" }

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the tab `key` from the v-for loop as follows :

```html
 <li v-for="(tab,key,index) in tabs" :key="tab" @click="currentTab = key">
    <div>
     <p>{{ key }}</p>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. But what is the 'key'? I can't understand, how it actually works here...

Comment: You're welcome, this how vfor works

Comment: the tab is the object value and the key is the object field